# POSIXlt not available for R version 3.01

Tags: r, package

I am trying install POSIXlt package, and I get the following result. I tried it in both Mac and Windows.

package ‘POSIXlt’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)

Any idea? I thought that this package would be available for 3.0.1. Do I need to load an earlier version of R (which one)? It is not ideal as I want to use some of the newer packages.
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you want to install a package called POSIXlt?  What makes you think that exists?

Comment: try typin `?POSIXlt` in the `R` console (or `RStudio`) and see what happens ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no research effort and a gross misunderstanding of the basic difference between packages and classes.

Answer (score 3):

It is a **class provided by base R**. If you have R, you have `POSIXlt`.

From current date:

```
R> unlist(as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date()))
  sec   min  hour  mday   mon  year  wday  yday isdst 
    0     0     0     3     7   113     6   214     0 
R>
```

From current time:

```
R> unlist(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time()))
   sec    min   hour   mday    mon   year   wday   yday  isdst 
 28.99  27.00  12.00   3.00   7.00 113.00   6.00 214.00   1.00 
R>
```

If one does not do `unlist()`, the output will be formatted ("pretty-printed").

Comment: base type or base class? `typeof(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time()))`

Comment: Right. `class` is better. Will amend.